# Error code 1048 encountered during SP call

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I'm experiencing a 'Column cannot be null' error for 2 columns, when I try to run a SP.

Source table A is defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_data`.`offer` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `hotel_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `source_system_code` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `available_cnt` INT NOT NULL,
  `sellings_price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `checkin_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `checkout_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `valid_offer_flag` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `offer_valid_from` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `offer_valid_to` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `breakfast_included_flag` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `insert_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Table B into which I am inserting the data:

```
 CREATE TABLE `calculate_USD` (
`counter` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dates` date DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`original_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
`currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`counter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the SP for the insertion:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE aid INT;
DECLARE avalid_from_date DATE;
DECLARE avalid_to_date DATE;
DECLARE hotel_id INT;
DECLARE original_price float;
DECLARE currency_id int;
DECLARE tempdt DATE;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE getdates CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id,offer_valid_from,offer_valid_to,hotel_id,sellings_price,currency_id 
from offer;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN getdates;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH getdates 
INTO aid,avalid_from_date,avalid_to_date,hotel_id,original_price,currency_id;

    IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;  
END IF;

set tempdt=date(avalid_from_date);

WHILE (tempdt <= date(avalid_to_date)) do
  insert into calculate_USD(dates,id,hotel_id,original_price,currency_id) 
  values(tempdt,aid,hotel_id,original_price,currency_id);
  set tempdt=tempdt+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
end while;


 END LOOP;
 CLOSE getdates;
 END
 //
```

When I call the SP, 
hotel_id & currency_id columns are instigating the error code.

If I assign them both NULL default values, the SP runs however, the hotel_id & currency_id values being inserted are all NULL like so (rest are OK):

```
counter  |    dates   |  id   | hotel_id | original_price | currency_id |
  1      | 2015-4-30  | 342523|   NULL   |     200        |    NULL     |
  2      | 2015-4-30  | 342524|   NULL   |     112        |    NULL     |
```

This is strange, because both have valid data in the source table.

Please advise.

Comment: Avoid naming variables and parameter as columns of your tables in your stored procedure.

Comment: I'm confused.  In your offer table you declare those two fields to be 'default null' but in 'calculate_USD' they are both 'not null'.  When you are attempting to do the insert, have those fields been assigned values or are they still null?  And when you say the SP runs when they are both default null, are you referring to the values themselves or did you modify the calculate_USD table structure?

Comment: I edited the source table above  that was originally misrepresented. Initially, hotel_id & currency_id were declared as not null in both tables. Under these conditions, I was unable to call the SP due to error 1048. If I re-created calculate_USD & declared the two fields as default null, I was able to call the SP. However, values for these two fields that were inserted into calculate_USD from offer,were all null.  These two fields had valid data in the offer table.

Comment: Check: [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Answer (score 0):

One option that can solve is:

```sql
.
.
.
DECLARE `getdates` CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
  `id`,
  `offer_valid_from`,
  `offer_valid_to`,
  -- `hotel_id`,
  `offer`.`hotel_id`,
  `sellings_price`,
  -- `currency_id`
  `offer`.`currency_id`
FROM
  `offer`;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

All I had to do was re-name the hotel_id & currency_id variables in the SP to something else and it worked.

Updated SP:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE aid INT;
DECLARE avalid_from_date DATE;
DECLARE avalid_to_date DATE;
DECLARE sp_hotel_id INT;
DECLARE original_price float;
DECLARE sp_currency_id int;
DECLARE tempdt DATE;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE getdates CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id,offer_valid_from,offer_valid_to,hotel_id,sellings_price,currency_id 
from offer;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN getdates;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH getdates 
INTO aid,avalid_from_date,avalid_to_date,sp_hotel_id,original_price,sp_currency_id;

    IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;  
END IF;

set tempdt=date(avalid_from_date);

WHILE (tempdt <= date(avalid_to_date)) do
  insert into calculate_USD(dates,id,hotel_id,original_price,currency_id) 
  values(tempdt,aid,sp_hotel_id,original_price,sp_currency_id);
  set tempdt=tempdt+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
end while;


 END LOOP;
 CLOSE getdates;
 END
 //
 call test_procedure();
```